# Error when using Asynchronous annotation in EJB

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1

On invoking an `@Asynchronous` method in EJB, I see an error getting logged though the method execution works fine. Any suggestion on what is going wrong?
EJB 3.1 on WebSphere V8

The interface is :

```
@Local
public interface MyService {
    @Asynchronous
    public void doJob(MyObj o);
}
```

The implementation class :

```
@Stateless
@Local(MyService.class)
public class MyBean implements MyService {
    @Asynchronous
    public void doJob(MyObj o) {

        // insert to DB

   }
}
```

**Error message**

*CWWAM1101E: In class {0} the method {1} is annotated with @Asynchronous but must be applied to a business method of a bean class or to a business method of a Local/Remote business interface.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a defect in WebSphere till V8.0.0.5 and a fix is expected in V8.0.0.6

Answer (score 1):

As you're implementing an interface (`MyService`) your bean doesn't expose a no-interface view. This means all methods for which the EJB container has to "do something", have to be defined in that interface.

It's very likely that `void doJob(...)` is not defined `MyService`. When in doubt, please show the full definition of `doJob` and `MyService`.

Comment: I guess the error is about having annotated the method declaration in the interface. Can you try removing `@Asynchronous` from `MyService`? You should only have the `@Asynchronous` annotation on `MyBean` then.

Comment: p.s. the `@Local` annotation is double is well. You need it only once. In this case, remove the one on `MyBean`.

Comment: Tried various scenarios. 1 - If annotation is added to the interface and implementation , then the asynchronous functionality works, and the error messages are logged.
2 - If annotation is added to the interface alone, then the error messages are not logged, but the functionality doesn’t work.
3 - If annotation is added to the implementation alone, then the error is logged, but the functionality doesn’t work.

Comment: That almost sounds like a bug in WebSphere :\ Last thing you could try is not implementing an interface at all. So, remove `implements MyService` completely and `@Local`. This shouldn't be necessary, but just for completeness.